# Unlock when sliding out physical keyboard

Tags: keyboard, lock-screens, sony-xperia-mini-pro

I got a Xperia Mini Pro with a physical keyboard. When I slide out the keyboard, it still have to slide on the screen to unlock it. Can I get to the password prompt with the keyboard movement alone?

Comment: That would be unsecure, wouldn't it? a) you could accidentally "slide open" the keyboard with the device in your pocket, and run something randomly; b) some "unauthorized person" could bypass your lock screen easily (when using a PIN/password/pattern lock).

Comment: Well, I mean that it should show the password promt when I open the phone, not that I have to open, slide and enter the password all the time.

Comment: AFAIK they are both connected, and you cannot get rid of the "simple slide" alone (without de-activating the other as well, disabling "keyguard" with e.g. *Tasker*).

Comment: Can't you just start typing your password? For example with Gnome lockscreen, if you simply start typing, the slider will automatically open itself and all your keypresses will still be captured by the password prompt even before the prompt is visible.

Comment: I actually don't know. And I cannot check as I don't have that phone any more. The most recent version of Android that it got is 4.0, so I presume that this question has no relevance any more.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible with tasker + secure settings plugin.

I dit it in a harder scenario (altough I'm an sk17i owner too) I used the above combination to unlock, force landscape, and wake up an alcatel dual sim phone paired with a Nuu minikey sliding bluetooth keyboard.

Comment: Could you say exactly how you did it?